Cython : How can we add default value to fused_type parameter?
I want my function that has a fused_type parameter to take a default value.
I already added int as a part of my fused_type. But I keep getting an error.
ctypedef fused test_type:
    double
    int
    str
    MyObject


def test_point(self,  a : test_type = 0):
    print("hahah")


[Error]
TypeError: Expected unicode, got int


The fused_type is used for types that Cython can optimize, like int, double, and custom Cython-defined types and you are using str which  is not a Cython type . so, you should use isinstance() to handle the string type.

@Peaky_001 you can definitely use str as a fused type. Cython can optimize it a bit. That doesn't mean that this particular use is sensible of course (I suspect it isn't)

@Peaky_001 I think the problem I have is not really about str or not. I just wanna know how to setup a default value with my fused_type parameter.

@DavidW Do you know to setup a default value with fused_type parameter?

The default value must work with all the fused types for that argument. So in this case I don't think you can.

@PunreachRany  yes  @DavidW is right, while  using fused_type, the default value must be valid for all the types within that fused type. Since 0 is not a valid default value for the str , you can't use it as a default value , when str is part of the fused_type.

@Peaky_001 It appears that you're right. I can't fused_type while str or MyObject are a part of the fused_type. Do you know which part of the documents it is mentioned anyway?
